# Space activities live: What are the current sources for video and data?

Tags: discussion, resources

Is this possible -- useful / advisable / add your personal criteria -- to start building a page that would be a good reference for primary sources references?

What are the current available sources for **live** data/audio/video broadcasting of space related activities?

- Manned / unmanned mission progress.
- Spacecraft position, status.
- Scientific probes and sensors data.

And how are they collected?

- DSN, TDRSS, etc.